# Why do an unexpected token "return" with forEach?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't ara return the unxpected token error, instead of 23 added to each value in the array?

```
        var aras = [1,2,3,4,5]
        let ara = aras.forEach(item => item + 23);
```

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything. Any return value is superfluous.

Comment: use `map` instead to return new array.

Comment: @VLAZ—per [*ECMA-262*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) it returns *undefined*, always. :-)

Comment: @RobG which is the default return value for any function that doesn't have an explicit return. Therefore semantically "nothing" is the same as "undefined" here as both refer to the concept of "void" - absence of a return value. JS represents that absence with `undefined` but it's still the same "void" as opposed to, for example, `Array#find()` where the result is *intentionally* the value `undefined` signifying no member of the array matches the predicate, rather than absence of any sort of result from the invocation. Shall we bike shed semantics more or is this enough?

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesnot [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) any value. So the value for `ara` in your statement will be `undefined`.

`Array.forEach` just loops through each element in an array, and perform an action. Here your action is `item + 23`, but it doesnot update anywhere.

If you want to genereate a new array from an existing one by making some changes to each element in the array, use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var aras = [1,2,3,4,5]
let ara = aras.map(item => item + 23);
console.log(ara);
```

Answer (score 1):

forEach does return undefined.
to return new array use `map`.

```
var aras = [1,2,3,4,5]
let ara = aras.map(item => item + 23);
```